# Simplest way to receive email to a lambda - AWS Simple Email

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, amazon-simple-email-service

I am new to SES and thought it would be a quick setup but its looking a bit more involved than expected. I also have to go through a client so I want to make sure I understand my options before I make any requests.

So I have a client who has set up an email mailbox in outlook, dev@clientdomain.com. I want to have emails sent to this go into a lambda for processing, so I was looking at SES. Do I need to go through the same setup as if I was going to be [sending emails](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/send-email-getting-started-migrate.html)? That is do I need to [verify a domain identity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/verify-addresses-and-domains.html) or can I get away with [verifying just an email](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/creating-identities.html#just-verify-email-proc)? Do I need to ask the client to [publish an MX record](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/receiving-email-mx-record.html) on their domain?

Tbh I was hoping I could just some email address in AWS that is linked to a lambda, and then have the client email forward to this. Is there nothing straight forward like this in AWS? I am able to [send emails with the client email following this](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-send-email-ses/), but how can I receive an email and parse it with a lambda the easiest way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[AWS Workmail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workmail/latest/adminguide/lambda.html) offers exactly this functionality (email on hosted test domain that routes to lambda of choice)
[image]